# Filter list of dates with same days in common using ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have two lists of dates. I’d like to be left with a list that contains only the days the two lists have in common. For this I’m thinking to use `filter` and `any` to compare the two.

```
const dates = [
  "2019-05-19T09:00:00.000Z",
  "2019-05-20T17:00:00.000Z",
  "2019-05-21T17:00:00.000Z"
]

const datesToCompare = [
  "2019-05-21T17:00:00.000Z"
]

// when filtered should leave us with:
[
  "2019-05-21T17:00:00.000Z"
]
```

For each item, I’ll need to compare it using a predicate function from `date-fns` called `isSameDay`. (As the name implies, it compares two dates and says if they’re on the same day).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [innerJoin](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#innerJoin)

> Takes a predicate pred, a list xs, and a list ys, and returns a list xs' comprising each of the elements of xs which is equal to one or more elements of ys according to pred.

```
R.innerJoin(dateFns.isSameDay, dates, datesToCompare);
```

Example:

```js
const dates = [
  "2019-05-19T09:00:00.000Z",
  "2019-05-20T17:00:00.000Z",
  "2019-05-21T17:00:00.000Z"
]

const datesToCompare = [
  "2019-05-21T17:00:00.000Z"
]

console.log(

  R.innerJoin(dateFns.isSameDay, dates, datesToCompare)

)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.29.0/date_fns.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to compare them using a function.

Comment: Updated answer to use `dateFns.isSameDay`